# Making 'app' available to other people's pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, messenger

I've got incoming messages working via webhook, but what I cannot understand is how I make this available to other users.

I run a SaaS that's used by many different organisations, so I want to be able to give those organisations (who each have a subdomain on my domain) the ability to 'connect to facebook messenger', so that all of the messages to their facebook page (whatever that may be), come into their portal view on my platform.

The only way I can see this working, is by getting each user to register as a developer, and go through all the set up that I did to get my test example working.

But I must be missing something? What's the workflow to enable this, simply, so that users can connect in this way?

Comment: You make the page admin login to your app and grant it the necessary permissions, and then you add your app to the subscribed apps of the page via the appropriate API call.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean exactly? I'm not sure how to do either of those things.

Comment: How implementing login and granting permissions works is what I would consider “basics”, so please go read up on that on your own. How to subscribe your app for webhook updates of a specific page, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/

Comment: Ok thanks - I'd understood that messaging wasn't part of the graph API, but maybe I'm mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple Facebook pages connected to your single Facebook app. But you would require permissions from Facebook for that. You can read about permissions here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/